# Unable to call outside variable from inside a class

Tags: php, oop, class

Need some help with inclusion of outside variables.

I have this file `lang.class.php`

```
class Lang {
    public $DefaultLang = 'en';

    public function __construct() {
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/system/lang/en.php");
    }

    public function MainLang() {
        return $this->DefaultLang;
    }

    public function Translate($String, $Array = "") {
        if($Array != '')
            $LangArray = $Array;

        echo $LangArray[$String];
    }

    public function __destruct() {}
}
```

The language file is included in the `__construct()`

And this file `en.php` which holds an array

```
$LangArray = array(
    "home" => "Home",
    "news" => "News",
    "info" => "Info"
);
```

The class is called by this: `$Lang->Translate('home')`.

This returns nothing, but if I do this `$Lang->Translate('home', $LangArray)`, it returns the value from the array_key `home`

So, how can I get the array without getting it via the function?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `require_*` or `include_*`, think about it like if the code in the included file would simply be pasted instead of the include directive. Therefore, if you include that file, you will have a variable called `$LangArray`. You can take that variable and assign it to a private property in the class, then use it.

```
class Lang {
    private $LangArray; // <- store the array in a private property

    public function __construct() {
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/system/lang/en.php");
        $this->LangArray = $LangArray; // <- assign the loaded array
    }

    public function Translate($String) {
        echo $this->LangArray[$String]; // <- use the loaded array
    }
}
```